# Wordpress images that are not scaling down on IOS mobile devices

Tags: html, ios, css, wordpress, mobile

I use an advertising plug-in on wordpress called WP Pro Advertising and a couple of my ad zones are not wanting to scale down when viewing on an IOS mobile device.

Here is the code to the "adzone."

```
<div style="max-width:970px; width:100%; height:250px;">
    <iframe src="http://southernpublishersgroup.com?wppasaid=1815" border="0" scrolling="no" allowtransparency="true" width="100%" height="100%" style="border:0;"></iframe>
</div>
```

Here is a screenshot of the site on mobile. That first image is a 970x250px adzone

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in your iframe style or css:

```
iframe {
  width: 1px;
  min-width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: That fixed it! Thanks so much!